want my current pipeline stuck in queue when previous pipeline failed
i want my current pipeline stuck in queue when previous pipeline failed. i don't want it will be done through script i want any other way. simply i want that when next schedule run the pipeline ,the pipeline stuck in queue because the previous run failed due to any other reason.
azure-pipelines.yml
pool: Default


schedules:
- cron: "*/3 * * * *"
  displayName: Every 10 minutes trigger
  branches:
    include:
      - main

variables:
  - group: dbbackup

parameters:
  - name: selectedDatabase
    type: string
    default: testdb
    values:
      - testdb
      - testdb1
      - testdb2

stages:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    selectedDatabase: ${{ parameters.selectedDatabase }}

template.yml
parameters:
  selectedDatabase: ''

stages:
- stage: Backup
  jobs:
  - job: BackupDatabase
    steps:
    - script: |
        mkdir "$(backupPath)"
      displayName: 'Create backup directory'

    - script: |
        sqlcmd -S $(sqlServer) -U $(sqlUser) -P $(sqlPassword) -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [$(selectedDatabase)] TO DISK = N'$(backupPath)\\$(backupFileName)' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'$(selectedDatabase)-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
      displayName: 'Backup SQL Database'  
- stage: Restore
  dependsOn: Backup
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.Backup.result, 'Succeeded'))
  jobs:
  - job: RestoreDatabase
    steps:
    - script: |
        sqlcmd -S $(sqlServer) -U $(sqlUser) -P $(sqlPassword) -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [$(selectedDatabase)] FROM DISK = N'$(backupPath)\\$(backupFileName)' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5" -o "$(backupPath)\\restore_log.txt"
      displayName: 'Restore SQL Database'

this is my script

What exactly does it mean pipeline stuck in queue? You want to queue a new build?

Do you please care to explain your scenario, i.e. why do you want to do this? There might be other solutions or workarounds to your problem.

i want if for any reason my backup stage fails, when the schedule run the pipeline, the scheduling pipeline remain in queue. again after 10 minutes when again schedule run the pipeline it remain in the queue and so on...untill i fix the backup issue.
simply i want when when my schedule run the pipeline the pipeline remain in queue

@nimranawaz, I add more detail in edit below, please have a check.

This request doesn't make much sense to me. If there is an error in the pipeline you should fix it ASAP and then run a new build, as mentioned by Wade. You could eventually add a Manual intervention task to to pause a YAML pipeline run to wait for manual interaction, but given that a new build will be triggered every 10 minutes, I don't think that makes much sense either.

@nimranawaz, cause there are some designed behavior of DevOps pipeline, i'm afraid it's not good idea to remain the pipeline in queue. Please check the details below, let me know if you have any queries.


i want my current pipeline stuck in queue when previous pipeline failed. i don't want it will be done through script i want any other way. simply i want that when next schedule run the pipeline ,the pipeline stuck in queue because the previous run failed due to any other reason.

Each run of a pipeline are independent, it's not supported to stuck current pipeline when previous pipeline run failed. Please refer to the doc of the queuing policies.

What can be achieved is to check the target pipeline run result, and determine current pipeline to run or not.
you can add a pre-step in pipeline, use rest api Builds - List to get the target build latest result. Please refer to my answer for the code sample. You need to filter to value[1].result for current pipeline, but value[0].result for other pipeline.
Edit:

i want if for any reason my backup stage fails, when the schedule run the pipeline, the scheduling pipeline remain in queue. again after 10 minutes when again schedule run the pipeline it remain in the queue and so on...untill i fix the backup issue. simply i want when when my schedule run the pipeline the pipeline remain in queue

You should be aware below limits in DevOps pipeline:

The options always and batch for schedule trigger are false by default. If you would like to run the pipeline with schedule trigger even previous run is failed, always should be set as true manually.



If you would like to remain the pipeline in the queue, you should notice the timeout limit as the pipeline will automatically finish. Consider self-hosted agent if you need long time for pipeline.



Each pipeline which is still running will keep an agent. If you would like to remain the pipelines, which means you need to have many agents waiting for job.

As stated at the beginning, each pipeline is independent, even new pipeline runs and remains in pipeline, it will report same error as the failed run before, unless you check previous run result at the beginning.


In above, it's not a good idea to remain the pipeline in queue. You should fix the issue and then start a new run.

"it's not a good idea to remain the pipeline in queue. You should fix the issue and then start a new run" - I completely agree.
